# Запуск .sh скриптов в termux сломался

Tags: android, bash, консоль, shell, termux

Я сделал скрипт, типо якрылка для моего termux, его задача открыть папку с сервером nodejs и ждать следующей команы. Текст скрипта выглядит так:

```
cd ../..
cd ..
cd path/to/my/dir
bash
```

Я добавил в конце сценария `bash`, потому что так после выполнения скрипта, окно термукса остается открытым и принимает команды дальше. Типо я пишу `npm start`, и там же запускается мой сервер, все круто.
Вдруг с termux что то произошло, я снес все его данные, переустановил, обновил. Снова создал этот скрипт для открывания моей папки. Но теперь там появилась такая проблема, что когда я пишу `npm start`, он мне отвечает `bash: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/npm: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. Зато если теперь ввести команду `$SHELL`,происходит типо инициация термукса, он выдает в ответ текст как при обычном запуске:

```
Welcome to Termux!
Community forum: https://termux.com/community
```

и так далее; ну и команды npm заработают нормально.
Проблема в том, что заранее записать команду `$SHELL` в конец в файл.sh не дает никакого результата. Помогите, объясните че ваще происходит.

Upd.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560819/termux-says-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory# обсуждают проблему типо такой.
Совет 1:  `pkg install termux-exec`
Но у нас уже `termux-exec is already the newest version (1:0.9).` :(

Comment: Ну а путь-то `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/npm` существует?

Comment: Разумеется. В обычном запуске термукса команда обращения по этому пути срабатывает. А вот после виджета со скриптом Алгоритм такой: пишу npm - ошибка; пишу $SHELL ,и потом npm - работает нормально.

Comment: Можно полный пример скрипта, который не пашет?

Comment: ```cd ../..
cd ../..
cd ..
cd storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.spck/files
cd Taxi_admin
bash```

Comment: Ну т.е. ты справедливо считаешь, что вот этот однострочник (однострочник???) можно воспроизвести у себя на любой машине?

Comment: Нет. А ты расскажи, как в здешних комментах сделать \n <br>возврат <br/> каретки```omg <br/> realy```

Comment: Есть кнопка под вопросом "править".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я конечно неграмонтый в этом плане, и до сих пор не понимаю что происходит. Но в конце скрипта надо поставить `login` вместо `bash`. Тогда в скрипте вызывается этот экран приветствия termux, и все дальнейшие команды работают корректно, включая нужную мне npm